# Deploying helm chart in Kubernetes with Jenkins

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, kubernetes-helm

- I installed my jenkins using this guide:

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/#install-jenkins-with-helm-v3

- And also I created the service account according to the article:

> kubectl apply -f jenkins-sa.yaml

- My pipelines is in it github repo:

https://github.com/joedayz/node-k8s-cicd/blob/main/Jenkinsfile

But When I execute my pipeline I got it error:

- helm upgrade --install --wait --set 'image.tag=22' node-app-chart ./k8s/node-app-chart

Release "node-app-chart" does not exist. Installing it now.

> Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists.
> Unable to continue with install: could not get information about the
> resource ServiceAccount "node-app-chart" in namespace "jenkins":
> serviceaccounts "node-app-chart" is forbidden: User
> "system:serviceaccount:jenkins:jenkins" cannot get resource
> "serviceaccounts" in API group "" in the namespace "jenkins"
>
> script returned exit code 1

I am using minikube, helm v3, docker hub, github. The repo is public.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"could not get information" ... "permission denied". Your error message suggests your jenkins ServiceAccount does not have privileges getting resources within its own namespace.

And given the name of the ServiceAccount jenkins tries to get is some "node-app-something", we should probably assume that beyond getting objects, Jenkins would eventually need to create them as well.

Anyway, you would want to create a RoleBinding, in your jenkins namespace:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins-admin
  namespace: jenkins 
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: admin
subjects:
- namespace: webapps 
  kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins
```

Using the `admin` ClusterRole is probably not the best pick. Still, if you are managing ServiceAccounts for your app, your pipeline may eventually create RoleBindings as well granting that ServiceAccount with privileges over your cluster. If you need to create RBAC configurations, admin would work for sure.

If you do not want Jenkins to manage privileges delegations within its own namespace, you may instead use the `edit` ClusterRole.

If you do not want Jenkins to create objects within its own namespace, you could go with the `view` ClusterRole.

Note that Jenkins may need `edit` privileges, assuming you did setup Jenkins Kubernetes cluster integration (and dynamic agents provisioning, running your Pipelines)

Going with `admin`: maybe you should consider deploying your applications into a separate namespace: don't grant Jenkins with admin privileges over its own namespace, rather grant those privileges over whichever namespace should host your jenkins-managed applications.

Comment: My service account was configured following it https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/master/content/doc/tutorials/kubernetes/installing-jenkins-on-kubernetes/jenkins-sa.yaml

Comment: I applied it command : kubectl create rolebinding jenkins-admin --clusterrole=admin --serviceaccount=jenkins:jenkins --namespace=jenkins -o yaml.   and the pods are created but the char is in status FAILED.  node-app-chart jenkins   1        2023-02-13 00:09:36.562544399 +0000 UTC failed   node-app-chart-0.1.0 1.17.0

Comment: ok. well, failed is the status, not the reason, .... I'm no magician... feel free to investigate a little and add your findings to your initial post

Answer (score 0):

I could do that works!!

1. In values.yamls

> serviceAccount:   # Specifies whether a service account should be
> created   create: false

No create service account. Because it's trying to create a service account with the name of the chart.

2. In jenkinsfile change the command to:

> sh "helm upgrade --install --namespace jenkins ${HELM_APP_NAME} --set
> image.tag=${BUILD_NUMBER} ./${HELM_CHART_DIRECTORY}"

Thanks for your time.